# Какими методами можно улучшить предсказания временного ряда с множеством аномальных значений

Tags: python, pandas, машинное-обучение, временные-ряды

Есть датасет с некоторым количеством ежедневных событий.  Ссылка https://disk.yandex.ru/d/BDsxHn15sU7hMA

Нужно спрогнозировать события на следующие n дней.
Данные имеют следующий вид:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения])

Декомпозиция данных на тренд, сезонность и остатки:
[image: В данных есть недельная сезонность]

В данных есть недельная сезонность.

Делал прогноз при помощи МL моделей (Линейные с регуляризацией, LightGBM, Catboost), но результат не очень хороший, вероятно из-за множества аномалий.
В качестве метрик использовал RMSE, MAE.
Для моделей использовал генерацию новых признаков.

```
def make_features(data, max_lag, rolling_mean_size):
    data['year'] = data.index.month
    data['month'] = data.index.month
    data['day'] = data.index.day
    data['dayofweek'] = data.index.dayofweek
    for lag in range(1, max_lag+1):
        data['lag_{}'.format(lag)]= data['events'].shift(lag)
    data['rolling_mean'] = data['events'].shift().rolling(rolling_mean_size).mean()
    return data
 

def model_linear(model):
    
    best_lag = 0
    best_roll_size = 0
    best_alpha = 0
    best_rmse = 10
    
    for lag in range(1, 100, 5):
        for roll_size in range(1, 100, 5):
            for alpha in np.logspace(-3, 1, 5):

                df = make_features(data_resample, lag, roll_size)
                train, test = train_test_split(df, shuffle=False, test_size=0.1, random_state=2021)
                train = train.dropna()
                
                X_train = train.drop('events', axis = 1)
                y_train = train['events']
                X_test = test.drop('events', axis = 1)
                y_test = test['events']
                
                if model == 'Lasso' :
                    lm = Lasso(alpha=alpha)
                elif model == 'Ridge' :
                    lm = Ridge(alpha=alpha)
                lm.fit(X_train, y_train)

                preds_test = lm.predict(X_test)
                rmse = mean_squared_error(y_test, preds_test) ** 0.5
                if rmse < best_rmse :
                    best_rmse = rmse
                    best_lag = lag
                    best_roll_size = roll_size
                    best_alpha = alpha
    return best_rmse, best_lag, best_roll_size, best_alpha, preds_test
```

```
model_lgb = lgb.LGBMRegressor(random_state=12345)
parameters_lgb = {'max_depth': range(5, 11),
                 'learning_rate': [0.001, 0.01, 0.05, 0.1],
                 'n_estimators': range(100, 300, 50)}
search_lgb = RandomizedSearchCV(model_lgb, parameters_lgb, cv = ts_cv, n_jobs = -1, random_state = 12345)
search_lgb.fit(features_train, target_train)
best_lgb = search_lgb.best_estimator_
predict_lgb_valid = best_lgb.predict(features_valid)
rmse_lgb_valid = mean_squared_error(np.array(target_valid), predict_lgb_valid)**0.5
print('Качество модели LighGBM на валидационной выборке:', rmse_lgb_valid)
```

Метрика RMSE на тестовом датасете получалась где-то 4-5, при том что в 50% значений имеют среднее значение 5.

[image: Предсказание]

На картинке видно, что модель вообще не учла разброс.
Пробовал также модель SARIMA, но результат примерно такой же.

Какие есть еще способы улучшить модель?

Comment: Помимо того, что написано в отличном ответе, а так ли уж вам нужно предсказывать именно значения событий по датам? Может они по своей природе достаточно стохастичны. Спросите бизнес - может ему будет достаточно предсказания усреднённого числа событий за какой-то период (неделю, например, ну или те же n дней)? Это будет гораздо проще сделать, думаю.

Comment: Ну то есть,  например, если бизнесу нужно планировать продажи и считать, сколько товара завезти в магазин, не всегда это нужно делать ежедневно, бывает, что достаточно предсказать продажи на неделю суммарно и завезти сразу товар на неделю вперёд.

Comment: На самом деле нужно предсказать количество событий на 1, 3 и 10 дни после последней даты.

Comment: Да, спасибо уважаемому  CrazyElf за очень емкое дополнение к моему ответу. При такой дисперсии на заключительном отрезке данных -  самое разумное - предварительно перейти к скользящему среднему и по нему уже проводить весь остальной анализ. На точность предсказания на конкретный день в данном случае я бы даже не надеялся.  Да, у вас не будет точного прогноза, но будет прогноз совокупный по нескольким дням. Вы же не температуру в конце концов предсказываете.

Comment: @spacenew Это учебное задание? Данные не очень располагают к тому, чтобы получить на них хорошее качество. По-хорошему тут нужно постановку менять, приспосабливать к данным. Ну, либо в данных всё же есть какая-то закономерность, нужно только фичи придумать, которые бы позволили её уловить. Это не всегда просто. Можно было бы попробовать ещё `LSTM` какой припахать, всяко бывает.

Comment: @CrazyElf Да, задача учебная.

Comment: @passant Подскажите, пожалуйста, как перейти к скользящему среднему.

Comment: @passant Разобрался. Сделал прогноз градиентным бустингом. Брал данные только за 2019 год, тестировал на 10% оставшихся данных. В качестве наиболее важных признаков, помимо лага оказались скользящее среднее и стандартное отклонение.

Comment: @spacenew -  результат картинкой хоть покажите. Любопытно взглянуть.

Comment: @passant https://skr.sh/sBiO2DFozuH?a. Теперь пытаюсь на основании обученной модели предсказать будущие периоды за рамками дат имеющегося датасета.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы не назвал ваш график после примерно января 2019 года -  как ряд с множеством аномальных значений. То что происходит примерно в указанный момент -  называется точной смены модели поведения ряда (Change Points Detection) и отображают ситуацию, при которой в объекте мониторинга происходят некоторые (очень часто нами не наблюдаемые изменения. В данном случае  - скачкообразно увеличилась дисперсия и изменилось матожидание. Эта информация между прочим для специалиста в прикладной области может быть крайне ценной.

В таких случаях обучать модель на всем ряде абсолютно бессмысленная затея. По сути после 06.2019 ваш ряд описывается моделью, которая не имеет никакого отношения к предыдущим значениям. А следовательно -  обучение надо строить исключительно начиная с точки смены модели. Это раз.

Если вы поступите таким образом и попробуете выделить составляющие модели, то возможно и тренд у вас станет более менее нормальном. То что у вас на рисунке -  трендовой составляющей назвать очень трудно. Скорее всего ваша модель требует включения интегрирующей  компоненты в ARIMA (параметр d в общепринятых выражениях), и очень возможно -  высших порядков.  Это два.

Такая большая дисперсия после смены модели ряда вообще-то говоря не дает вам надежды на предсказание существенно более качественное, чем то, что вы уже имеете. И это особенность ваших данных, а не дефект методов. Попробуйте  первые два шага. Немного улучшите модель. Но на чудо надеяться не приходится. Это надо просто осознать. И это три.

Останутся вопросы -  задавайте, попробуем ответить.

Comment: Взял только 2019 год https://skr.sh/sBhykOEcPNp?a, декомпозиция: https://skr.sh/sBhV5l992LY?a

Comment: Уже на много лучше.